# Assemblies won't build in Sonar/Jenkins run

Tags: c#, .net, jenkins, .net-assembly, sonarqube

I am relatively new to Jenkins and Sonar, but I have been tasked with getting a code quality run on our [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)/[.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) code and have hit a few problems.

Initiating from Jenkins, the Sonar run is locating the assembly in our project and then failing to build it, saying it cannot locate them.

I have included an extract of the output below:

```
16:45:25.508 INFO  - Using the following Visual Studio solution:
D:\jenkins\build001\workspace\G_Release\Sonar\Source\G.sln
16:45:25.629 INFO  - Locating the assembly for the project: G.DataA...
16:45:25.630 INFO  - The following candidate assembly was not built:
D:\jenkins\build001\workspace\G_Release\Sonar\Source\G.DataA\bin\Debug\G.DataA.dll
16:45:25.630 INFO  - The following candidate assembly was not built:
D:\jenkins\build001\workspace\G_Release\Sonar\Source\G.DataA\bin\Release\G.DataA.dll
16:45:25.630 WARN  - Unable to locate the assembly of project
D:\jenkins\build001\workspace\G_Release\Sonar\Source\G.DataA\G.DataA.csproj
```

This happens for all assemblies!

Because it is doing this for each of the assemblies in the solution I am assuming it is some overriding factor/configuration I have missed out on.

Answer (score 0):

First Build the solution in Release mode(without sonar). Then check your sonar parameters file and a command line argument such as "sonar.dotnet.buildConfiguration=Release"into that file.
Then run your sonar analysis. Hope this helps !!!